# Things Went South

Tags: expressions

**If things went south** we better have some plan...

Is *went south* a racial term or it's okay to use it in normal conversation to refer if things went wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the OED, this meaning of ‘south’ comes originally from stock markets.

South on a map is obviously down at the bottom, and when stocks go downwards, towards the ‘south’, they devaluate; hence the expression ‘go south’.

There is no element whatsoever of it being a racial term. I can’t even imagine how ‘south’ would be racially loaded at all—if anything, ‘southern’ (in American English) is a *culturally* loaded term. Hardly a *racially* loaded one.

Comment: AmE here, and you're correct, no racial or cultural overtones to the term, going South. It's racially/culturally equivalent to "going to hell in a hand-basket, or "up s*** creek (usually without a paddle)."